# How to get the value of radio button which is printed in the rows in the table created by sql in php code

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble in getting the value of radio button for each row of the table plus the id of that row fetched by while loop . this is table for getting the attendance of students and save it against their ids . 
but i am unable to do so as i have pasted the radio button in loop in echo statement.

If i get the value in php code it just take the value of radio button but it does not take the value of that rows id. But I want both of them at a same time

Here is the code for table and radio button

```
<?php
    $sql = "Select grno, CONCAT(stdname ,' ', stdlname)AS sname   from student";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);
    if($result->num_rows >0)
    {   
        while($rows = $result->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $id = $rows['grno'];
            $name = $rows['sname'];
            $sch = $rows['grno'];
            $asql = "Select * from attendence where lid = '$id'";
            $aresult = $conn->query($asql);
            $a= 'add';
            $b= 'Present';
            $c= 'Absent';
            $d= 'Leave';
            echo "
                <tr>
                <td><a href = 'view.php?id=".$id."'>".$name."</a></td>
                <td>".$sch."</td>
                    <td><form method='post' >
                    <input type='radio' name='att' value='PRESENT' />".$b."
                    <input type='radio' name='att' value='ABSENT' />".$c." 
                    <input type='radio' name='att' value='LEAVE' />".$d." 
                <input name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' value='Enter' />
                    </form>   </td>";
        }
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $att=$_POST['att'];
            $date = date('Y-m-d', time());
            $ssql = "Select * from attendence where date = '$date' and lid = '$id'";
            $sresult = $conn->query($ssql);
            if($sresult->num_rows > 0)
            {
                echo "<script>alert('Today`s attendence already inserted.');</script>";
            }
            else
            {
                $insql = "Insert into attendence(lid, date, status) values('$id', '$date', '$att')";
                if ($conn->query($insql) === TRUE) {
                    echo "<script>alert('Attendence record Inserted');</script>";
                } else {
                    echo "<script>alert('Error Occurred');</script>";
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

When I write it like this then it work fine but the value of that id is not entered in database . Can you tell me how can i put the value of radio button in that echo statement or else how can I pass that value of particular row of while loop when the submit button is pressed. Because now if I print the value of `$id` in the code of `ISSET` submit button then it gets the id of last row but I want to get the id of the row on which I press the radio button.

or in second method if i wanna send the value of radio button plus id to the next page for example

```
 echo "
                    <tr>
                    <td><a href = 'view.php?id=".$id."'>".$name."</a></td>
                    <td>".$sch."</td>
                        <td><form method='post' >
                        <input type='radio' name='att' value='PRESENT' />".$b."
                        <input type='radio' name='att' value='ABSENT' />".$c." 
                        <input type='radio' name='att' value='LEAVE' />".$d." 
                    <a href = 'view.php?id=".$idd."&amp; att=".$att."'><input name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' value='Enter' /></a>  
                        </form></a>   </td>";
```

how can i do that

Comment: Do I get your question right that you want to submit all radio buttons in the table when clicking on submit?

Comment: No i just wanted to entre a single value present absent or leave against a single id . On which the button is marked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every row has its own form that can be submitted separately. One possibility is to add a `hidden` field to each row containing the id of that row. In your PHP script that is called when clicking on the submit button, you can `UPDATE` or `INSERT` your entry according to this id.

```
<form method='post' action='YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT'>
  <input type='hidden' name='row_id' value='" . $id . "'/>
  <input type='radio' name='att' value='PRESENT' />" . $b . "
  <input type='radio' name='att' value='ABSENT' />" . $c . " 
  <input type='radio' name='att' value='LEAVE' />" . $d . " 
  <input name='submit' type='submit' id='submit' value='Enter' />
</form>
```

In your PHP script (called `YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT` in this case), you can check for `$_POST['row_id']` and use this value to determine the row where the `Enter` button was clicked. I hope that I read your code correctly because I assumed that `grno` is your unique identifier.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $id = $_POST['row_id']; // add this line
  // ...
  if($sresult->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "<script>alert('Today`s attendence already inserted.')</script>";
  } else {
    $insql = "Insert into attendence(lid, date, status) values('$id', '$date', '$att')"; // $id is used here
    // ...
  }
}
```

EDIT: You are wrapping your form into an `<a></a>` element that could prevent the submission of your form because it is triggered before `Enter` (submit) can be triggered. You might rethink this structure.

Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in order to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: in php script what i am suppose to write ?  $_POST['row_id']?

Comment: I added a hint on how to do this above. You were getting always the `$id` of the last inserted row because you were not setting it after finishing your loop that was generating your table. As a result, `$id` contains the value of the last iteration (= row). IMPORTANT: Please change your SQL statements to prepared statements in order to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: thank you so much sir it worked  i was stuck on this for weeks but thanks to you i solved it. :-)

Comment: sir i have another question . i am student of MCS. its my final smester and  now i am  making my final year project on topic Learning management system . can i ask it here or should i post another question

Comment: @ayeshazafar please mark this question as accepted if you are happy with my answer. I think it depends on the question. If it is related to another problem I would suggest opening a new thread (and maybe post the link here so that I'm able to try to help you immediately).